# Fail to initiate static variables in c# of Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

I was trying to make a singleton in **Unity 2017**.

```
public class Singleton {

    public static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    static readonly float FLOAT_VAL = 3.5f;
    static readonly int INT_VAL = 3;

    private Singleton() {
        Debug.Log("FLOAT_VAL = " + FLOAT_VAL);
        Debug.Log("INT_VAL = " + INT_VAL);
    }
}
```

I expected to see the output of **"FLOAT_VAL = 3.5"** and **"INT_VAL = 3"**. However, it came out with the output of **"FLOAT_VAL = 0"** and **"INT_VAL = 0"**. Then I deleted both "readonly" modifiers, leaving "static" and still got two zero.

What happened to the initiation or construction of this singleton? How can I correctly give the values to the static variables? Is there anything to do with Unity? (I chose il2cpp when building the project, but this was tested under Editor Mode)

By the way, I figured out that the initiation of the variable **"instance"** didn't start until the first call (I used to think that all static vars get initialized when the assembly is loaded.). Is it also another Unity feature or just normal?

Comment: just normal. This is how .Net works.

Comment: What you mean by "just normal"? The delayed initiation? Or the unexpected values?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't have to modify your question and say that it is solved. People will know it is solved when you accept answer and you did in this case.

Comment: Statics not initialising until the first reference is a normal C# thing.  Personally, I use a lazy-loader pattern for singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields get initialized in the order they are declared.... so since your instance comes first, your other values are zero.   If you move them above your instance they will have the values you expect

Comment: Yes, that works. I have already been told that initiations of the static come with no orders. Should realize the dependence in static will make a mess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the C# language specification

§10.5.5.1

> Static field initialization
>
> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed ***in the textual order in
>   which they appear in the class declaration.*** If a static constructor
>   (§10.12) exists in the class, execution of the static field
>   initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static
>   constructor.Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at
>   an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static
>   field of that class.

So basically, because you wrote `instance` first, it is initialised before `FLOAT_VAL` and `INT_VAL`. Reverse the order and you will see your expected results:

```
public class Singleton {


    static readonly float FLOAT_VAL = 3.5f;
    static readonly int INT_VAL = 3;


    public static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
        Console.WriteLine("FLOAT_VAL = " + FLOAT_VAL);
        Console.WriteLine("INT_VAL = " + INT_VAL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> If your class contains static fields, provide a static constructor that initializes them when the class is loaded.[MSDN]

Add a static constructor to initialize your static variables